# How to remove a number from another number using bitwise operators?

Tags: c#, c, bit-manipulation

How do I remove for example `2` from `123` and returns `13`, by using bitwise operators? I have no idea how to do this.. it's possible? Thanks in advance.

Comment: you meant to obtain `13`, `103` or `121`?

Comment: @haylem: `13`. Updated question.

Comment: is this homework? or why would you need to do this?

Comment: Are your numbers in base 8, 16, or 4? Then this is easy ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're suggesting is possible, but wouldn't really make sense to do. Below are the values representations in bits (only showing relevant bits, everything further left is a zero):

2: 000010 || 123: 1111011 || 13: 001101

There's no logical way to change 123 into 13 with bitwise operations. It would better to turn it into a string or character array, remove the two then cast it back to an int.

Comment: Sure there is. If we aren't limited to *just* "use the constants 2 and 123" :-)

Comment: Thanks. I will convert it to string and back to int. I was just looking for a possible micro-optimization.. :)

Comment: @pst Did you mean 'if we are' ? Generating a mask at run time would be so much harder than doing it with strings/char arrays. I can't imagine how you would even make that work...

Answer (score 2):

What other cases are there? It may be possible to generalize this at an integer level if there is some sort of pattern, otherwise you're really just looking at string replacement.

The `2` in `123` is actually `2E1 (10100)`, and the `2` in `1234` would be `2E2 (11001000)` neither of which are related to `2 (10)`, at least in bitwise form. Also, the "number" on the right side of the removed number would need to be added to the number on the left side of the removed number / 10.

i.e, to go from 123 to 13:

```
Located "2".
Number on left (x): 100
Number on right (y): 3
y + (x / 10) = 13
```

and to go from 1324 to 134

```
Located "2"
Number on left (x): 1300
Number on right (y): 4
y + (x / 10) = 134
```

Unless there's some pattern (i.e you know what positions the numbers are in), you'll just have to `.ToString()` the number, then do a `.Replace("2", "")`, before doing an `int.Parse()` on the result.

**EDIT:** Someone upvoted this answer and I realised my previous implementation was unnecessarily complicated. It is relatively straightforward to 'iterate' over the digits in a base-10 number and shouldn't require recursion.

New solution below, performance is better but this is a huge micro-optimisation:

```
static int OmitDigit(int number, int digit) {
    var output = 0;
    var multiplier = 1;
    
    while (number > 0) {
        var n = number % 10;
        number /= 10;
        
        if (n != digit) {
            output += (n * multiplier);
            multiplier *= 10;
        }
    }
    
    return output;
}
```

Result:
`1554443`

Comment: Did some testing and even with the lack of optimization, this out-performs `int.Parse(1000000001.ToString().Replace("0", ""))`, not by a lot though haha

Answer (score 0):

Since we're working with base 10 numbers, manipulation in base 2 is ugly to say the least. Using some math, removing the nth digit from k, and shifting over is

```
(k/pow(10,n))*pow(10, n-1) + k%pow(10, n-1)
```

In base 2, the `<<` and `>>` operator acts like multiplying by a `pow(2, n)`, and `&` with a mask does the work of `%`, but in base 10 the bits don't line up.

Comment: I tested it out but it does not seem to work. I tried setting k=123 and n to 2(for the second place)  and got 15.3 is there any other operations missing here or am I using k wrong?

Comment: I believe that `(k/pow(10,n))` needs to be floored in order to work.

Answer (score 0):

This is very awkward, but if you really do must have bitwise operations only, I suggest you [convert the number to BCD](http://people.ee.duke.edu/~dwyer/courses/ece52/Binary_to_BCD_Converter.pdf). Once in BCD, you basically have an hexadecimal numbers with digits between 0 and 9, so removing a digit is very simple. Once you're done, convert back to binary.

I don't believe anybody would want to do that.